# Google Apps Script Web App MailApp/GmailApp.sendMail() not working when parameter is sent using doGet()

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function doGet(e) {
  var email = e.parameter.method;
  var subject = "Hello";
  var body = "Hi, I am ";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.method);
}
```

Above is my Apps Script published as a web app. Logger is working fine, but the mail is not being sent. 
I am trying to run the script by browser, going to following link. I was expecting a mail to be sent to some.body from my mail. 
I have already authorized the script to send my mails.

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/[---my script--- ]/exec?method=some.body@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in a try-catch block to catch the exact error. You may also want to test for your email quota.

```
function doGet(e) {
 try {
  var email = e.parameter.method;
  var subject = "Hello";
  var body = "Hi, I am ";
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.method);
  Logger.log(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota());
 } catch (error) {
 Logger.log(error.toString());
 }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but didn't help. The script is showing success, only Logging the e.parameter.method which is inside 'try'. Even Logger.log(MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota()); didn't happen. It is totally ignoring MailApp part. Thanks for answering anyway.

Comment: You got to republish the web app as a new version.